# Save a timestamp to Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a date picker and time picker dialog to choose what date and time to save into a Firestore document. I am also using java's `LocalDateTime` to store locally what date and time I picked from the picker dialogs. Putting the `LocalDateTime` variable that I created for the `Map<String, Object>` and saving it into Firestore, saves the date and time as a `Map` field, and not a timestamp field. I saw a similar question here at this website but the solution is using `LocalDateTime`'s predecessor, `Date`. I am not planning to replace `LocalDateTime` with the old version just to achieve what I am trying to do. If you guys know how to store the date and time to Firestore using `LocalDateTime`.

LocalDateTime Initialization:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
int yr = localDateTime.getYear();
int mos = localDateTime.getMonthValue();
int dy = localDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
int hr = localDateTime.getHour();
int min = localDateTime.getMinute();
```

Date and Time Picker Dialog:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(DateTimeChoose.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
                    localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(year, month+1, day, hour, minute);
                    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Elections Will End On:\n'MMM dd, yyyy'\n@ 'hh:mm a");
                    electionsText.setText(dateTimeFormatter.format(localDateTime));
                }
            }, hr, min, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }, yr, mos-1, dy);

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Storing date and time to Firestore:

```
CollectionReference admin = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Admin");

    Map<String, Object> electionEndTime = new HashMap<>();
    electionEndTime.put("electionEndTime", localDateTime);

    admin.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    String adminEmail = "";
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshots = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots) {
                        adminEmail = documentSnapshot.getId();
                    }

                    admin.document(adminEmail).set(electionEndTime, SetOptions.merge());
                }
            });
```

Screenshot of Firestore document:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object?

Comment: It's good seeing you here sir @AlexMamo. It's not that I don't want to use a Date object. I just want to know if there is a way to put a timestamp using the user-friendly `java.time`. If there is no way to do that, then using a Date object is my alternative option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object, as it's not a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). What you can use instead, is a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object. You can simply write such a value as you already do in your code.

Comment: If that is the case, then I will just convert `LocalDateTime` to the classic java `Date`. Thank you for informing me that `LocalDateTime` is not a supported data type. Is there any chance that you will include these types of data in the future?

Comment: Yes, you should do a conversion. I really don't know that but you can send that request directly to the Firbease team.